# Nginx-Ingress Controller are compatible with Network Security Policy or not?

Tags: azure-devops, nginx, ingress, azure-kubernetes-service

I have created one application where I use **Nginx-Ingress Controller version 3.29.0**. Without using **network security policy** I'm able to access my application. But, after applying network security policy, I'm unable to access my application.
I checked all logs and troubleshoots the whole application but there is nothing anything odd. all my services and nginx ingress controller are working fine. But still when I go to access my application it will show me error that, **"To long to respond"**.

Can any one help me with this?
**Is there anything like nginx-ingress controller is not compatible with network security policies or what?
and how can I solve this?**

Nginx-Ingress Controller version - 3.29.0
Kubernetes version - 1.19.7

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is the compatibility, need to really see your configuration to be sure. But most likely, you block something wrongly. If you use the default network policy api `networking.k8s.io/v1` notice that it only allows what is defined.